# How to populate a field referenced by composite _id in Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following schemas:

```
var WorkSchema = new Schema({
  _id:            Object,  // {client: String, project: Number}
  title:          String,
  description:    String
});

var TimeWorkedSchema = new Schema({
  _id:           Object,  //  {client: String, date: Date}
  work:          {type: Object, ref: 'Work'},  //  {client: String, proyect: Number}
  hours:         Number,
  description:   String
});

var w  = mongoose.model('Work', WorkSchema);
var tw = mongoose.model('TimeWorked', TimeWorkedSchema);
```

Fields `Work._id` and `TimeWorked.work` are comparable objects with identical properties. Then, I want to populate the TimeWorked model with the corresponding Work data as usual:

```
tw.find().populate('work').exec(function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Prints:

```
[{
"_id": {
    "client": "clientX", 
    "date": "2017-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"},
"work": {
    "_id":{                     ┐
        "client": "clientX",    |
        "project": 1},          | invariable
    "title": "ABC",             |
    "description": "defgh"},    ┘
"hours": 4,
"description": "bored"
},{
"_id": {
    "client": "clientY", 
    "date": "2017-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"},
"work": {
    "_id":{                     ┐
        "client": "clientX",    |
        "project": 1},          | invariable
    "title": "ABC",             |
    "description": "defgh"},    ┘
"hours": 8,
"description": "funny"
},{...etc...}
]
```

As you can see, in all returned objects, the populated `work` field is the same object.

However, if I delete the populate method (`tw.find().exec(...)`) I get the original `work` fields, which are actually different.

I think that Mongoose has not implemented this type of population. How can I relate both schemas to get combined data in a query?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

> Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs.

You will need `$lookup` for this one.

```
tw.aggregate({
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "works", // collection name
          localField: "work",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "work"
        }
   }).exec(function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the same result. Finally I have chosen to select in a separate process all the Works mentioned in the initial query, to add them one by one to the HoursWorked (in old style). The main problem was to have opted for MongoDB (enthusiastic about the novelty) in a project that does require a relational database.

Comment: You are welcome but this should've worked. You should share the query that you've if you don`t mind. I have tested this code. I can add the test data if you prefer.